# PHP Parsing Hotel data (name, location etc..) and print them with foreach loop in Table

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
$curl = curl_init();
$response = curlPost($curl, $url, $headers, http_build_query($body));

$data = json_decode($response, true);


if ($data["success"] === true) {
  $hotels = $data["hotels"];

foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    echo $hotel['name']."<br>";

    foreach ($hotel as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === "id"){
            continue;
        }
        if ($key === "name"){
            continue;
        }
        echo "{$key}: {$value}" ."<br>";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL."<hr>";
}
 } else {
 echo $data["reason"];
}
?>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"> NAME OF THE HOTEL </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>key</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
```

This is my code . As you see i am parsing with curl some data more specifically name, id, location etc.. of some hotels and store them in a variable called `data`. I know how to print the data, but i don't know how to place the data in the table below. For example i wanted to say `<th colspan="2"> HOTEL PARIS HILTON </th>` below the `<td>location</td> <td>USA</td>`etc..
Help anyone ? thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th colspan='2'> {$hotel['name']} </th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<thead>";

    foreach ($hotel as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === "id"){
            continue;
        }
        if ($key === "name"){
            continue;
        }
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$key}</td> "."<td>{$value}</td>"."<br>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo " </tbody>";
    }
    echo    "</table>";
    echo    "<hr/>";
}
  } else {
   echo $data["reason"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop you can actually echo your table' contents:

```
<table>
<?php
foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    $columnsCount = count($hotel) - 2;

    echo '
    <tr>
        <td colspan="' . $columnsCount . '">
            ' . $hotel['name'] . '
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>';


    foreach ($hotel as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'id' || $key === 'name'){
            continue;
        }

        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Your comment refers to a regular table rendering, which is not very different from what I gave you in the first place.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <?php
            $columns = array_keys($hotels[0]);
            echo implode('</th><th>', array_diff($columns, ['id']));
        ?>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
        foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
            $hotel = array_diff_key($hotel, ['id' => false]);
            echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $hotel) . '</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i see what you did there but can you do it table from top to the bottom? table like this `https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro`